# Consistent ways/ rules to define types with generators.

Tags: logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Is there a way/ set of rules to define types with their generators which is proven to be consistent (obviously the proof need not be in the same type theory). For example (I think) the following way is allowed in Idris:
Let $Pre$ be the collection of predefined types. Then we can define a type

$$ New : T_1 \to ... \to T_n \to Type ,$$ (where $T_1$, ..., $T_n$ are in $Pre$) with generators of the following form, 
$$genNew : S_1 \to ... \to S_m \to New,$$ (where $S_1$, ..., $S_m$ are either in $Pre$ or is $New$).

More generally when we give a type, we give its introduction and elimination rules. What are the possible kinds of such rules for which it is proven that a contradiction will not arise.

Comment: By consistent do you mean "_the empty type is not inhabited_"?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa yes

Answer (score 1):

The 'set of rules' you are refering to is known as the 'strict positivity condition'. It is a bit more permissive than the conditions you wrote.

It is proven to be enough: see for instance the answer to the question ["Intuition Behind Strict Positivity?"](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42627/intuition-behind-strict-positivity/42637) on cstheory.stackexchange, and its reference to [Nax Mendler's PhD dissertation](http://www.nuprl.org/documents/Mendler/InductiveDefinition.html.).